# I created a drop down list and it won't move to the top of the screen?

Tags: html, css

hey I'm a beginner of html & Css and i couldn't find a solution for my problem 
i tried to fix it many times by adding different positions but it just ruins it more.
so i searched every where and there wasn't any solution of my exact problem, i just started 2 days ago so if u can give me any tips for fixing such problem i will highly appreciated.

here is my code:

```css
*{margin: 0%; padding: 0%;}


#whole {
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
  
 }

#img1
  {width:250px;height:250px; 
   position:absolute; top:10px; left:6px;


   }
#small { font-size:30px; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; 
  padding-left: 24px; padding-bottom:40px;
  position:absolute; top:290px}

#bird {font-size:45px; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; 
  padding-left: 61px; 
  position:absolute;top:250px;left:27px}

#img2 
 {width:1600px; height:380px; 
    } 


#menu ul ol 
 { 
 float:left; 
 width:200px ;
 height:px;
 background-color:red;
 opacity:.9;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
 color: white;
 

 }

#menu ul ol {
   
} 

#menu ul ol a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  display:block;}

ul ol a:hover {
 background-color:#89cff0;

}

ul ol ul ol {
 display:none;

}
ul ol:hover ul ol{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>not avaliable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<div id="whole">
<body>
 <h1 id="bird">Scar</h1>
 <h3 id="small">For digtil Markting</h3>
 <img src="imgs/head.jpg" id="img2">
 <a href="project1.html"><img src="imgs/web.png" id="img1"></a>
 
 
</body>
</div>
<header class="pro">

  

</header>

<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <ol><a href="https://www.google.com/">About us </a>
   <ul>
    <ol><a>Mission</a></ol>
    <ol><a>Out team</a></ol>
    <ol><a>Creators</a></ol>
   </ul>
  </ol>
  <ol><a href="#">Services</a>
     <ul>
    <ol><a>Wbsites</a></ol>
    <ol><a>Themes</a></ol>
    <ol><a>Security</a></ol>
    <ol><a>Cost</a></ol>
           </ul>
  </ol>
  <ol><a href="#">Contact</a></ol>
  <ol><a href="#">Careers</a></ol>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html structure is wrong. check here -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp . Essentially you have the <head> where you import fonts, styles, libraries etc. Then the <body> which includes <header> ( which includes nav, logo etc ) then you have <main> ( which includes the <content> and sidebars ) then you have <footer>. Your structure doesn't look at all like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not sure till end what you what and how you want it to look. ..
But i edited your code like this maybe it helps:

Also as **Mihai T** told: Your html structure is wrong.

```css
*{margin: 0%; padding: 0%;}


#whole {
 color: white;
 font-family: Arial Narrow;
  
 }

#img1
  {width:250px;height:250px; 
   //position:absolute; top:10px; left:6px;


   }
#small { font-size:30px; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; 
  padding-left: 24px; padding-bottom:40px;
  position:absolute; top:290px}

#bird {font-size:45px; text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black; 
  padding-left: 61px; 
  position:absolute;top:250px;left:27px}

#img2 
 {width:1600px; height:380px; 
    } 

#menu {
  position: absolute;
}
#menu ul ol 
 { 
 float:left; 
 width:200px ;
 height:px;
 background-color:red;
 opacity:.9;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
 color: white;
 

 }

#menu ul ol {
   
     
} 

#menu ul ol a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  display:block;}

ul ol a:hover {
 background-color:#89cff0;

}

ul ol ul ol {
 display:none;

}
ul ol:hover ul ol{
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>not avaliable</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="whole">
  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
      <ol><a href="https://www.google.com/">About us </a>
        <ul>
          <ol><a>Mission</a></ol>
          <ol><a>Out team</a></ol>
          <ol><a>Creators</a></ol>
        </ul>
      </ol>
      <ol><a href="#">Services</a>
         <ul>
          <ol><a>Wbsites</a></ol>
          <ol><a>Themes</a></ol>
          <ol><a>Security</a></ol>
          <ol><a>Cost</a></ol>
             </ul>
      </ol>
      <ol><a href="#">Contact</a></ol>
      <ol><a href="#">Careers</a></ol>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
 <h1 id="bird">Scar</h1>
 <h3 id="small">For digtil Markting</h3>
 <img src="imgs/head.jpg" id="img2">
 <a href="project1.html"><img src="imgs/web.png" id="img1"></a>
  </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: First of all your menu div was outside of <body> and was standing after all other content. Also i commented out this code as it pulled image on the top ` //position:absolute; top:10px; left:6px;` . .. I already forgot but i think that is all i done! :) Basically biggest issue was wrong structure/order in HTML. Remember content should be between `<body></body>`

Comment: `<div id="whole">` needs to be inside `body` tag too.

Comment: @Simran true! Did not saw it :O